# Amazon SES - unable to create SMTP User

Tags: java, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have been trying to configure `Amazon SES` to send emails from my `Java Spring MVC Web application`. I am trying to get the `SMTP credentials` for my account. I am able to create SMTP user with the root account, but not with another user account for which I have full access permissions for `SES. I get the following error when I try to create an SMTP user:
[image]

I have the following permissions for `SES`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ses:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And also the following for `IAM`

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1489248224000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:ListUsers",
                "iam:GetAccountSummary",
                "iam:ListAccountAliases"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::12345678:user/"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am not sure what more permissions are to be added to that I can create an SMTP user to get the SMTP credentials for sending emails via SES

Comment: I do not have much experience with SES, but I doubt if only the root user has the permission to create an SMTP user thereby getting the SMTP credentials

Comment: @edwiser, not sure if only root account can create SMTP credentials, haven't seen that specifically mentioned in any of the docs

Comment: `Resource": [ "arn:aws:iam::832416434181:user/" ]` doesn't make sense.  The user is the principal, not the resource.  The resource you are looking for is `"*"`.

Answer (score 1):

In your IAM policy, try adding an `*` or the actual username at the end of the resource:

```
"Resource": [
            "arn:aws:iam::832416434181:user/*"
]
```

Comment: I had tried that. It didn't work. Also, i tried "Resource": "*" event that dint work